# What is the most efficient way to create dynamic dropdowns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, index-match

I am working on a spreadsheet for work to track team progress. We have several different teams all entering data onto the same sheet. There's a lot of tutorials on dynamic dropdowns for single entries, but I have not been able to find anything that resembles what I need.

I made a sheet with all the teams, and their members, and created named ranges to make things easier. I then make a helper sheet to create a sort of temp table to get the correct names
I have come up with two solutions. One uses `INDEX` and `MATCH`, and the other uses `INDIRECT`.

The sheet will be archived weekly, but we will be expecting hundreds, if not thousands, of entries per week. I would like to know which one of these solutions will be more efficient when the sheet gets larger; or is there another simpler solution that I have not been able to find?

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fv04wy44bk-kBx4kUOnPyn0GbirbMF6mrWjfhS5q-Zg/edit?usp=sharing) is an example sheet of what I am looking for with 5 teams of 10 people each.

Comment: How many people will be using the spreadsheet?  Will they each be using their own sheet?

Comment: Currently we have 75 team members, the majority of them will be using the same sheet

Comment: How many will use the dropdowns?  Is there only one set of dropdowns?  Is there a concern with people using same dropdowns from different computers and overwriting each other?

Comment: Everybody will be using the dropdowns. Anytime you have a sheet with multiple editors, especially less tech savvy ones, you’ll probably run into people overwriting each other; but that’s what version history and/or CTRL+Z is for

Comment: It's not good practice to have multiple people manually entering data in the same spreadsheet. You should consider [creating a form](https://forms.new) instead and link it to the sheet.